# How to cancel touchesMoved:withEvent:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a query regarding touches on the view:

I have a parentView(frame is (0,0,768,1024)) which contains two subViews(A and B),A frame (0,0,512,768) with tag 100 and B Frame (512,0,512,768) with tag 200.

I implemented touches methods `touchesBegan:withEvent:`  `touchesMoved:withEvent:`  `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

When I started touch from A to B `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods gets fired as expected

**I need to implement:** As the touches reaches B from A, touchesEnded of A should get fired and touches began of B be fired and vice versa .I have my own logic in their respective methods.Can some one suggest how to achieve the same.

Comment: Did you implement touches methods `touchesBegan:withEvent:` `touchesMoved:withEvent:` `touchesEnded:withEvent:` in your A and B views?

Comment: A view and B view are two instances for a class which is subclass of the UIView and I implemented those methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional behavior.  Usually, if you touch the **Cancel** button, and your finger slips onto the **Delete** button as you lift it, you don't want to accidentally delete something.

However, I've had the situation where I did want touches to be passed around like this.  Much like @ejazz, I moved the work to the view that contained both A and B.  This had user interaction enabled, and implemented `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.

When touches moved over the subviews, it sent appropriate messages.  I just switched the subviews on and off, but you should be able to just call `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` on the appropriate subview if necessary.  If you need to know when touches begin and end, you will need to track the previous view associated with each touch - or just call its `previousLocationInView:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` class. Attach it to the parent view, set the delegate.

You can now follow the states and location. So when the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` check if the location is in A or B, and when the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` check if the location is in B or A.

You can check if the tap view contains the A or B view with

```
CGRectContainsRect(<#CGRect rect1#>, <#CGRect rect2#>)
```

And then using view.frame

Comment: Even If i use the UIPanGestureRecognizer still I cant cancel the gesture in the middle of the gesture changing.if A's UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged and pan point is not in the same view then I need to start B's UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and vice versa.

Comment: If you move the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the parent view, and add some BOOL states (i.e. isInB, isInA) then you can follow the changes and switches yourself.